# Trying to integrate LowDB with existing db.json

Tags: node.js, express, json-server

I am trying to load an existing db.json file inside lowDB.

I have followed the instructions from the [tutorial](https://github.com/typicode/lowdb), however nothing that was explained seems to work.

```
const low = require("lowdb"),
      FileSync = require("lowdb/adapters/FileSync"),
      adapter = new FileSync("db.json"),
      db = low(adapter);

   console.log(db.getState()) //logs empty object
```

Location of db.json is in the same directory as this file. Why can't I access this json file/set it as source for my LowDB?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, solved this one. The problem was that LowDBs FileSync adapter reads the filepath based on CWD, not on the directory where the server file is located. I fixed this by using a relative path based on where my node_modules and package.json is located (in my case it was **./server/db.json**).